# Inactive form and waits for user input and then activate again

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing my semester project and I need little help

Is there any way that a form can be inactivate and some popup box will open and ask user for input, when user types his input, this input will automatically assign to some variable (in inactive form) and then the form will activated.

Example:

How many processes do you want to create ?? (form in background is inactive, and pop up box is waiting for user to type his input), user types 4 and this 4 is assigned to our main form and then form will activated and perform his tasks.

P.S: I know about storing value, I'm just confuse in inactivation and re-activation of form. And Without creating a new form, Is it possible to have such popup box.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe is that of a **model form**. A model form is opened by a parent form and, while shown, prevents the parent form from being interacted with.

You can create a new form and show it as model like this:

```
ParentForm:

...
Form childForm = new ChildForm();
childForm.ShowDialog();
int result = childForm.Result;

ChildForm:

public int Result;

void OnSubmitButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Result = inputBox.Value;
    Close();
}
```

Plus error checking, prevent user from closing the child window, etc. You can show the child window in the parent's Loaded event if you need the value as soon as the form is ready.

Comment: It really really works !!!
It solves two problems, first explained above and the my start up screen problem which. I was using backgroundprocess thing.
Thank mate!